# Display Tab View on change of activity

Tags: android

I have designed a tab view with buttons in the home screen. When i click a button to link to another activity , the tab bar vanishes. Is there any way so that when i change activity pages in the tab view , tab view does not vanishes means can we define a parent class for all activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this the thing you are looking for your solution

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html